# Range Slider with Angular2 Form Control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder, form-control

How can I create a range slider in Angular similar to https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range where the min and max values are pushed to $gt and $lt respectively?

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  'price': this.fb.group({
    '$lt': [null, []],
    '$gt': [null, []]
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ng2-nouislider](http://tb.github.io/ng2-nouislider/).

It has multiple options for Range Slider.